# RTX2060 and i5-4430 - does this combination make sense?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming, pc

I'm planning an upgrade of a gaming PC. This is my current setup:

```
CPU: Intel Core i5-4430 @ 3.00GHz
MB: ASUS H-81 Plus
GPU: GeForce GTX 560 Ti
RAM: 8 GB
```

I want to replace GPU with RXT2060 and later at some point upgrade CPU to i7.

### The question is:

#### Is this plan viable? Will I have noticable performance growth if I only upgrade the GPU? Or must I upgrade both at once?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Comment: @ArtOfCode excuse me but where in my question do you see the techincal support / troubleshooting request? I'm not asking for that! I'm literally asking to "to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendation"

Comment: @ArtOfCode removed all mentions of dead GPU from my question. Probably it was what caused the misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HW Recs! In general we don't answer viability questions or "does-this-work?" type questions. Our site is best suited for direct purchase recommendations (e.g. GPU upgrade recommendation or CPU upgrade recommendation, preferably as seperate questions if possible).